# Providing context in questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118698/format-html-to-be-suitable-for-json-data-c-sharp) regarding formatting strings in C#. I was trying to convert multiple lines of HTML into a single line so that it could be sent in a JavaScript Object.

The suggested tag of json popped up so I figured it wouldn't hurt to provide this extra context - i.e. my reasoning for the desired outcome.

This was not received well at all as I received downvotes and edit requests. I assumed the additional context would be helpful so that someone could suggest an alternate method if they saw one. Is this the wrong way to go about it on my behalf?

Comment: Your question actually has to do with regex, not json. Arguably in this instance, it's meta-information. Saying "if you read the question you might be able to figure it out" in your comment isn't how you clarify, instead you should edit to provide more details in your question if you felt that json should have a bigger part in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) (emphasis mine)

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are **a means of connecting experts with questions** they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

In your case, it's not as if a JSON export (who might follow or favourite the JSON tag) could come along, and have any meaningful thing to say about your question. It may have *featured* some JSON, but it wasn't *about* JSON. It was *about* removing newlines with C# regular expressions.

Providing context in questions about what you're trying to do is usually a good thing, but it doesn't need to be tagged with everything that it might touch on or mentions.

Comment: Thats true. You did get me thinking however... what does your average day look like for a JSON expert? Perhaps its narrow mindedness but I didn't think there was a lot to it.